# problem in importing controlnetmodels from diffusers.model

Tags: python, diffusers

There is problem in importing control net models from diffusers .models inside a python file  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSQVN.png), specifically in line 28.

I tried to degrade the diffusers version to 0.16.x but that didn't helped.
Need help on how to import it.